# arguments about existence

Tags: theology

I think therefore I am, so why should I exist? It seems as long as I exist there is a problem of explanation. It seems the only natural way it could be is for nothing to exist at all, as then no explanation is needed. But none the less this seems to be in direct disagreement with observation.

So self evidently I exist, the universe exists with no conceivable explanation which isn't an arbitrary, choice to exist.

I have considered that maybe nothing naturally needs something to set it apart as to what it is, and perhaps that is where we or I exist. Buy intuitively I can not escape the idea that there should only be empty, nothingness in need of no explanation. The only other idea which seem as natural is that there must be a God, and for what ever reasons, most likely forever inconceivable to us, made the apparent, necessary choice for me and this universe to exist. Thus due to my observations I and anyone capable of basic reasoning must conclude there is a God, or fundamental entity which made the choice for all of this to exist, pre-dating all cause and effect as the initial cause.

Now of course you could say aliens made the choice, or higher dimensions, or this is a simulation or anything but this segregates us and them into two different universe. I can suppose the same questions there as well as here and you get another never ending problem of explanation. So you could argue this problem either never goes away, or if it does its due to God, which for me feels like the explanation.

If anyone can be mature enough and voice their intuition on this matter and not anyone particular beliefs please do so.

Comment: Do you suppose that trees contemplate their existence? Perhaps it's a human problem?

Comment: I don't know what argument that makes, on the philosophical significance of trees vs humans?

Comment: it doesn't matter if minds are physical or otherwise.. it seems (we don't know for sure) that only humans ask why we're here. Humans are capable of asking a lot of questions, some of which are nonsensical. Like what would happen if the number 3 didn't exist.

Comment: The point is that doesn't explain why humans are conscious. So I can ask how moons form, but I can't ask why abstract laws govern the universe, why there is a universe. Seems that is an unatural and arbitrary choice to not have a fundamental cause, which quite frankly while MAYBE not proven, there could be a fundamental cause. Further it seems you should have to leave some amount of uncertainty as I leave.

Comment: "as long as I exist there is a problem of explanation" Why ? What does it mean ?

Comment: "the only natural way it could be is for nothing to exist at all" What does it mean "natural way" here?

Comment: See [Descartes’ Ontological Argument](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/descartes-ontological/) : "But if the mere fact that I can produce from my thought the idea of something entails that everything which I clearly and distinctly perceive to belong to that thing really does belong to it, is not this a possible basis for another argument to prove the existence of God? Certainly, the idea of God, or a supremely perfect being, is one that I find within me just as surely as the idea of any shape or number.  1/2

Comment: And my understanding that it belongs to his nature that he always exists is no less clear and distinct than is the case when I prove of any shape or number that some property belongs to its nature. (Fifth Meditation)" 2/2

Comment: But also Descartes' version of the argument is subject to the main onjection regarding *ontological arguments* in general: on what ground we can assert that a *concept* (or idea) has "in itself" the "property" of existence?

Comment: Yeah see Godels ontological proof.

Comment: Soliciting opinions or intuitions from the users, is off-topic on this site. As for those of professional philosophers, there is a long tradition of explaining ["Why is there something rather than nothing?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_why_there_is_anything_at_all) that you can read about under the link. So it is unclear what an unswerable question here is.

Comment: @marshalcraft i think the problem is, how do we know which questions humans can ask, are answerable? And i'm not personally sure that 'why are we here' is answerable. We just 'are', like time is, or electrons are.

Comment: There are indeed fundamental limits to what knowledge we can acquire, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma - Bottom line is, if you try to create an ontology starting from your existence, you will need to _choose_ what to believe. If you decide to build on your _sense experience_, you will eventually reach a limit to understanding...

Comment: That is absurd as I could argue all of philosophy is off topic, go on a rant about semantics, formal deductive systems, where theories are algorithmically proven from axiom, then have my axiom challenged, and mean while, though interesting in its own right, is now entirely a different topic.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you feel the need to take existence as a given based on your observations and experiences. But what do you mean by 'existence'? Are you sure you're right to do this?

There is a metaphysical theory for which nothing really exists. This states that what appears to exist has no intrinsic existence but exists only in dependence on an Ultimate (non-Kantian) phenomenon, such that by reduction this prior phenomenon is all that is truly real. All the rest would be appearances.

This solves your problem and allows all existing things to be reduced for a fundamental theory, but at the cost of taking mysticism seriously. History shows that you will not find another solution for your problem. The moment we reify existence and assume that what is Ultimate exists in the same way as pianos and galaxies our philosophy becomes paradoxical and incomprehensible.

There would be no need for God but there would be a need for a state, substance or entity that can fulfill the same function and give rise to the 'created' world along with you and me. Contrary to Kant this would be knowable and verifiable but only by way of a study of consciousness. The evidence of our physical senses will always be physical so physics can be of no help in explaining the existence of the physical.

Metaphysics endorses the idea that existence as we normally think of it, being paradoxical and inexplicable as you note, is a mistake, and a different view of it would be required for a plausible explanation. A review of the literature of philosophy and theology will confirm this.

If you choose to ignore this reducible view of existence than you will be stuck with the problems you raise, as are all philosophers who assume existence and reality are the same thing.

Comment: I have read nothing here capable of correcting the issues I describe. I would further group this into the choice to not explain beyond finite quantities. But yet the consideration of infinite limits, regardless of their physical existence, exist abstractly, and have proven quite useful in the physical world.

Comment: I do thank you however for your thoughts, I will consider them more thoroughly.

Comment: @marshalcraft - I'd be happy to expand the answer if asked, but I don't quite understand your comment so cannot respond. . .

Comment: Peter, would you agree that existence is the fallout of perception? (For the sake of clarity for marshal.)

Comment: @RandyZeitman - I'm, not sure quite what you mean. Do you mean existence  depends on perception or must be established by perception? This would not be the view I'm describing.

Comment: You asked what do you mean by existence. Well isn't the answer perception? All that exists is perceived. There's no existence with perception. They're not synonyms but connected.

Comment: @RandyZeitman - Okay. In this case then either perception and existence are not fundamental.or they both are. I'm endorsing the former view.

Comment: @PeterJ I don't know what fundamental means in that context.

Comment: I have spent some time in my younger years, so certain that nothing was the only sensible case, but have moved on because quite frankly, more than nothing does exist. I would group this in into theory about dualism, requiring the exterior of nothing to exist as well, and thus everything, and we just find ourself in one particular corner of it all. But still what caused daulism? And so that's why I don't take much comfort in that way of going about things.

Comment: Also I will note, though unrelated, I am Christian personally. But I still have a need to rationalize the modern world. I don't believe that my expectations of a benevolent God hinder my rational, at least no more then an atheist, who just the same expects there to be no God and in many cases, simply demands there not be one. But part of our world is fixed one way or another regardless of what we demand.

Comment: Also thank you for your answer, it seems involved. It seems some have issue with calling something god. I can minimally find this understandable, in this philosophical context there doesn't seem to be any easy relations with typical notions of God. I personally believe the fundamental existence of good and evil, are similarly shown to be fundamental to the world, but this is far more advanced then the mere existence of God. Subject for seperate question.

Comment: @marshalcraft - Note that what I say above is not inconsistent with Classical Christianity, the Gospel of Thomas, the Philokalia. the Mystical Theology, the Nag Hammadi Library and so forth. Your view seems to be heading in that direction. .

Answer (score 0):

"Buy intuitively I can not escape the idea that there should only be empty, nothingness in need of no explanation."

Well that's quite a problem since nothing can't be observed. 
There is no "is" nothing if there's no observer.

Yes, I am saying perception of reality = reality.

The concept of 'things existing that I can't perceive' is a perception ... as is the idea that you wouldn't exist to perceive them.

"Thus due to my observations I and anyone capable of basic reasoning must conclude there is a God, or fundamental entity which made the choice for all of this to exist, pre-dating all cause and effect as the initial cause."

Why can't the universe have always existed?
Wouldn't anything before the universe also be 'the universe' since the universe means all? 
In other words, all can't be created as the creator would also be needed.

So if you believe there must be a god then you must believe there must be infinite, successive gods ... which is why it seems one must conclude the universe always existed.

As for life in the universe please read about Abiogenesis.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abiogenesis

"Abiogenesis, or informally the origin of life, is the natural process by which life has arisen from non-living matter, such as simple organic compounds.

While the details of this process are still unknown, the prevailing scientific hypothesis is that the transition from non-living to living entities was not a single event, but a gradual process of increasing complexity that involved molecular self-replication, self-assembly, autocatalysis, and the emergence of cell membranes."

Comment: No, I discussed the issue, of expanding the universe to "this god" and chain of segregated universe with their own gods in the next. They wouldn't be the fundamental cause in this case, the point that is truely outside of it would be. Basically, this universe on it's own doesn't have a casual right to exist, however God, being God, and all Cause, does. So then thats all there is, God. It's the only thing which isn't in requirement of explanation, or choice to ignore questions, mark them as non well formed, etc.

Comment: @marshalcraft  I agree. There's no causal right for the universe to exist ... therefore it must have always existed. But I don't know why god is all-cause ... if god exists doesn't god exist in the universe? If god is supernatural then god is moot as supernatural isn't real.

Comment: I'm not opposed to a viewpoint or phrasing that the universe is God, except that I would prefer, "a part of God" and not rule out that more exists which is forever beyond our experiences. But oddly enough, in my spare time I like to not use Acham's razor, and frame hypothesis, especially on that which may seem to not matter. Like searching for classical theories which violate belly's inequality, to explain q.m.